# Multiple conditions in LIKE operator

Tags: php, mysql

i am getting multiple values in this $languages like(php,Ruby) i want spilt that and how to check that split values in this query

```
SELECT * FROM software_capability where languages LIKE '%$languages%'
```

Comment: Could you provide more details about what you are trying to do, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this.

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE interests LIKE ('%sports%', '%pub%')
```

This is syntax. Exploded your $language and put each item in `'%$item%'`

Answer (score 1):

As in other languages Mysql also supports [regexp](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) for pattern matching that could be used in such cases. I would simply create a query string separated by the `delimiter (|)` out of the `$languages` array, and use that in the query --

```
$query_string = implode("|", $languages);
SELECT * FROM software_capability where languages REGEXP $query_string
```

The result will be same using `LIKE` clause as given in other answer.

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained what it does.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM software_capability where CONCAT('%',languages,'%') LIKE '$languages';
```

assuming that $languages is 'php,Ruby'

Answer (score 0):

If `$languages` is comma (,) separated values, then you can try with `IN` command of `mysql`

```
SELECT * FROM software_capability where languages IN ($languages)
```